# How to set column titles as subtitles in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot several graphs of an excel data in Python with a simple command. I am currently using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(12,12))
data_cols = df.columns[8:16]
for data_col, ax in zip(data_cols, axes.ravel()):
   ax.boxplot(df[data_col])
```

I want to set column titles that I choose for data_cols as subtitles of subplots. Do you have an idea about how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like ``ax.set_title(df.columns.value[i])`` where ``i`` is the index of your column?

Comment: When I use that, titles not matching with plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to iterate over those axes and columns you want to plot to and from. So if you want to plot the last 8 columns of the dataframe you also need to iterate over the last 8 axes.

This would then allow you the use the column name as title, `ax.set_title(data_col)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.rand(5, 16)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(6,6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
data_cols = df.columns[8:16]
for data_col, ax in zip(data_cols, axes.ravel()[8:16]):
   ax.boxplot(df[data_col])
   ax.set_title(data_col)

plt.tight_layout()   
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, It worked! But, I changed `axes.ravel()[8:16]` with `axes.ravel()[:8]` because I want to match first 8 axes with last 8 columns.